# Getting Message Threads, modfied after [date]

Tags: php, gmail, gmail-api

**The Why?**
I'm playing around with the GMAIL api, for a minor project at work

**The Wanted Result**
What I'm trying to get from the Gmail API, is all message threads modfied after a certain timestamp/date.

**What do i have so far**
So far i manage to get all threads created after a certain date - by using the standart gmail search queries see - https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190.

**The Problem**
It's great i can get all the Message Threads after a certain date, but the problem is when i have my queried set as:

```
after:[todays date - 7 days)
```

This will show me all Message Threads, up to 7 days ago - but what when i have a Message Thread, created 8 days ago and still getting updated?. What is my best option to get all message threads, **modified** from now to 7 days ago?
Checking all message threads, all the time is not an option :)

**The code**

```
 $client = getClient();
 $oService = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
 $sUser = 'me';
 $tsMailsAfter   = '1554280000';
 $sIn            = 'INBOX';

//before;, after:, in:(inbox, sent)
$aThreads = getlistThread($oService, $sUser, 'after:'.$tsMailsAfter.' in:'.$sIn);

function getlistThread($service, $userId, $aQuery = '') 
{
$threads = array();
$pageToken = NULL;
do
{
    try 
    {
        $opt_param = array();
        if ($pageToken) 
        {
            $opt_param['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
        }
        $opt_param['q']         = $aQuery;
        $threadsResponse = $service->users_threads->listUsersThreads($userId, $opt_param);
        if($threadsResponse->getThreads()) 
        {
            $threads = array_merge($threads, $threadsResponse->getThreads());
            $pageToken = $threadsResponse->getNextPageToken();
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
        $pageToken = NULL;
    }
}
while ($pageToken);
return $threads;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved my issue by just using a search query (with :after) on ->listUsersMessages() and then collecting the ID's in an array(). Its not the most optimal solution, having a search query :modified_after would be the best solution - this solution defiantly works for **my purpose**:)

```
        function listThreadsToUpdate($service, $userId, $sQuery = '') 
{
    $pageToken = NULL;
    $messages = array();
    $opt_param = array();
    do 
    {
        try 
        {
            if ($pageToken) 
            {
                $opt_param['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
            }
            $opt_param['q']         = $sQuery;
            $messagesResponse = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages($userId, $opt_param);
            if ($messagesResponse->getMessages()) 
            {
                $aMessages = array_merge($messages, $messagesResponse->getMessages());
                $pageToken = $messagesResponse->getNextPageToken();
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception $e) 
        {
            print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    } while ($pageToken);

    $aThreadsToUpdate = array();
    if(isset($aMessages) && !empty($aMessages))
    {
        foreach ($aMessages as $oMessage) 
        {
            $aThreadsToUpdate[] = $oMessage->getThreadId();
        }
    }
    return array_unique($aThreadsToUpdate);
}
```